# How to alert car winner and reset images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a program with two images for cars and three buttons. The `PauseRace` button works fine. The `StartRace` button works except when an image hits 800 pixels the images should stop moving and an alert should show up declaring the winner. Lastly, the `ResetRace` button should move the images back to the begin and set all other values back to 0.

```js
var timer;
var ArandomNumber;
var BrandonNumber;
var x = 0
var q = 0

function GatherData() {
  ArandomNumber = GetRandomNumA();
  BrandonNumber = GetRandomNumB();

  var thedivtop = document.getElementById("Move1");
  x += ArandomNumber;
  thedivtop.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
  var thedivbottom = document.getElementById("Move2");
  q += BrandonNumber;
  thedivbottom.style.marginLeft = q + 'px';
}

function StartRace() {
  timer = setInterval(GatherData, 500);

  if (document.getElementById("Move1") == 800 + 'px' && document.getElementById("Move2") != 800 + 'px') {

    alert("Car 1 has won the race!");
  } else if (document.getElementById("Move1") != 800 + 'px' && document.getElementById("Move2") == 800 + 'px') {
    alert("Car 2 has won the race!");
  }
}

function GetRandomNumA() {
  var x = Math.random();
  x = Math.random() + 56;
  return x;
}

function GetRandomNumB() {
  var q = Math.random();
  q = Math.random() + 56;
  return q;
}

function PauseRace() {

  clearInterval(timer);
}

function ResetRace() {
  timer = 0;
  x = 0;
  q = 0;
  document.getElementById("Move1") == 0 + 'px';
  document.getElementById("Move2") == 0 + 'px';
}
```

```css
.moveable {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <b>First to 800 pixels wins!</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Both cars start at 0 pixels.</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Start Race" onclick="StartRace()" />
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Pause Race" onclick="PauseRace()" />
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Reset Cars" onclick="ResetRace()" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="Move1">
    <img id="Car1" class="moveable" src="delorean.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="Move2">
    <img id="Car2" class="moveable" src="duster.jpg" />
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements must be in `GatherData()` and you can just use `x` and `q` to check which is in front. Also, you need to check if one is ahead of the other in case both cross the finish line at the same time. I also added a `clearInterval` after the race finished.

```js
var timer;
var ArandomNumber;
var BrandonNumber;
var x = 0
var q = 0

function GatherData() {
  ArandomNumber = GetRandomNumA();
  BrandonNumber = GetRandomNumB();

  var thedivtop = document.getElementById("Move1");
  x += ArandomNumber;
  thedivtop.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
  var thedivbottom = document.getElementById("Move2");
  q += BrandonNumber;
  thedivbottom.style.marginLeft = q + 'px';
  
  if (x >= 800 && x > q) {
    alert("Car 1 has won the race!");
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else if (q >= 800) {
    alert("Car 2 has won the race!");
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

function StartRace() {
  timer = setInterval(GatherData, 500);
}

function GetRandomNumA() {
  var x = Math.random();
  x = Math.random() + 56;
  return x;
}

function GetRandomNumB() {
  var q = Math.random();
  q = Math.random() + 56;
  return q;
}

function PauseRace() {

  clearInterval(timer);
}

function ResetRace() {
  timer = 0;
  x = 0;
  q = 0;
  document.getElementById("Move1") == 0 + 'px';
  document.getElementById("Move2") == 0 + 'px';
}
```

```css
.moveable {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <b>First to 800 pixels wins!</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Both cars start at 0 pixels.</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Start Race" onclick="StartRace()" />
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Pause Race" onclick="PauseRace()" />
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Reset Cars" onclick="ResetRace()" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="Move1">
    <img id="Car1" class="moveable" src="delorean.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="Move2">
    <img id="Car2" class="moveable" src="duster.jpg" />
  </div>


</body>
```